# clang Build error with Titanium / external iOS module

Tags: ios, clang, titanium-modules

I have been trying to write and integrate an external SDK into Titanium by creating a custom module, and keep on getting this error...I have recreated the Module and the Client 2-3 times, cleaned and build the code, updated the Module.xcconfig and downloaded and updated the Titanium SDK. I am at my wits end, and any help / suggestion on this will be truly appreciated. This may be something silly that I may have overlooked. Thanks!

Here is how my module.xcconfig looks...

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -F "/Users/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/VoxModule1"
     -framework "/Users/Downloads/DragonMobileSDK_1.4.5/SpeechKit" -framework
SystemConfiguration -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox
```

Here is the error that I am getting (when I compile it via XCode)....I have spent a few days trying to solve this, and any pointers you may have will be a great help. Thanks!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKVocalizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcom.test.voxmodule1.a(ComtestVoxmodule1Module.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SpeechKit", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libcom.test.voxmodule1.a(ComtestVoxmodule1Module.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to also include the SpeechKit.Framework
That's all I had to include to get mine working.

Gav